# Vendor testing delay hitting timelines

Tags: scope, timeline

I've been asked to produce a report on the effect of vendor delays on my timeline.

I have a team of 6 engineers who are supposed to be a PC roll out team. The Vendor is delayed because of various applications other parts haven't been tested in the new environment. Which is leaving the rollout team idle for x amount of days. This is a given but how do I record this time and the knock on effect on the timeline.

On paper the engineers should be knocking out 150 to 160 laptops per week. They work 8 hour days, so one per hour. We are rolling out 1700 pieces. How can I report this in excel, with the time constantly being impacted because of various applications and or  infrastructure sometimes not being in place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution would be to load the values in excel of your planned work, and then load the values of your actuals, and you can display progress using a cumulative graph.  Here's an example:  [image]

I used 155 as your planning value and loaded it assuming equal numbers each week, which produced a flat loaded schedule.  Then I made up actual values but showed it to be behind the plan.  From here, you can forecast where you are headed based on actual performance using a simple forecast formula in excel, or you could bring a bit more sophistication by using Earned Schedule analytics and it will predict when you will finish based on your schedule performance to date.

The graphic is a nice way to show to stakeholders--easy to read and digest and hard to dispute in terms of your forecast from it.

Adding two types of forecasts: formula in excel and ES:

[image]

Comment: You could add a 3rd column of the adjusted forecast, if you want.

Comment: @DannySchoemann, Added.